# several hours but still stuck on dropdown submenu - inherited css creating empty box under parent menu - jfiddle incl

Tags: css

ive tried for a few hours now to trace down how to get rid of a weird box that is appearing on my css menu. There are two layers of submenus. the second level submenu is situated where i want it on the right of it's parent menu, but once it appears- upon hover - a box of the same height appears under the parent menu too. this weird box is also oddly offset. It just needs to go away.
Any CSS gurus out there?
Thank you so much for looking!!!

[jfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dXn3P/)

```
#pagebody {
position: inherit !important;
width: 831px;}

#pagebody-inner {
position: inherit !important;
width: 100%;}

#alpha, #beta, #gamma, #delta {
display: block;
float: left;
min-height: 1px;
position: inherit !important;}

#centernav {
width: 831px;}

#dropnav {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #D2D3D5;
height: 40px;}

#dropnav ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;}

#dropnav ul ul {
display: none;}

#dropnav ul li {
border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
float: left;
font-size: 14px;
list-style: none outside none;
margin-left: 0;
padding: 10px 20px 15px 19px;
position: relative;
text-align: left;
text-decoration: none;
z-index: 88888;}

#dropnav ul li:hover > ul {
display: block;}

#dropnav li a {
color: #000000;
text-decoration: none;}

#dropnav li a:hover {
color: #990000;
text-decoration: none;}

#dropnav li ul {
background-color: #D2D3D5;
display: none;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 40px;
z-index: 99999;}

#dropnav li:hover ul {
display: none;
padding: 0;
width: 200px;}

#dropnav li li {
border-right: 0 solid #000000;
border-top: 1px dotted #FFFFFF;
display: list-item;
list-style: none outside none;
padding: 5px 0 5px 20px;
width: 180px;}

#dropnav li li a {
color: #000000;
text-decoration: none;}

#dropnav li li a:hover {
color: #990000;
text-decoration: none;}

li#main {
padding-top: 6px;}

#subnav li {
background-color: #A443A5;
height: 20px;}

#subnav2 li {
background-color: #A2A3A5;
left: 200px;
position: absolute;
top: -40px;
width: 280px !important;
z-index: 99999;
display: none;
height: 20px;
}

<div id="centernav">
  <div id="dropnav">
    <ul>
      <li id="main"> <a href="#">Home</a>
    <ul id="subnav">
      <li><a href="#">About this site</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>

<li id="main"> <a href="#">Training Modules</a>
  <ul id="subnav">
      <li><a href="#">See Here: </a>
        <ul id="subnav2">
          <li><a href="#">1:</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2:</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">3: </a></li>
          <li><a href="#">4: </a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">and here</a>
      <ul id="subnav2">
        <li><a href="#">what is up with</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">the box under </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">parent menu </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">to the left </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">-it mirrors </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">height of subnav </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> and is positioned lower </a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: You shouldn't have multiple HTML DOM elements with the same ID. ID should be unique. You have multiple "li" with id="main"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what seems to be happening is your `li`s are positioned away from the `UL`. (The grey box in question is in fact the `UL`. But because of the following CSS code they are positioned away from their parent `UL`:

```
#subnav2 li {
    background-color: #A2A3A5;
    display: none;
    height: 20px;
    left: 200px;
    position: absolute;     /* <-- position absolute with the 200px left and -40px top causes list items to be positioned away from their parent UL */
    top: -40px;
    width: 280px !important;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

I would try removing that positioning and positioning the `UL` instead.

FWIW here's an example of a simple 3-tier CSS drop-down menu: http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/nrAPu/

Comment: OK. but i'm still lost. If i create add these to the first level submenu ul, it'll reposition that level and not the second level.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but the main issue is you need to position the entire `UL`, not the `LI`s individually,

Comment: i think i got it. I created dropnav ul ul ul and added the positioning under that - which seems to work . Thank you for the help!

Comment: Right on. Glad I could help. Happy coding.